# Why does Keras validation vary so much and differ from training

Tags: keras, tensorflow2.0

New to Tensorflow/Keras. I'm training a binary classifier for time sequence data. The plot I see frequently looks like this:

[image: Training vs Evaluation Data]

From someone more experienced, is this plot symptomatic of something obvious? The validation accuracy seems to change drastically while the training accuracy doesn't. My dataset is about 85% negative examples and 15% positive.